# Spring does not rollback if an unique constraint error happens with a list. How to enable rollback for whole list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, transactions

I have the following entity with the Constrainsts:

```java
// Associated entry
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"userId", "associationDate"}))
public class Association extends coreEntity {

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private Long userId;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private LocalDate associationDate;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private LocalTime start;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private LocalTime end;

       private Duration breakTime;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       private Set<ProjectEntry> projects;
    // getter setter

}


// the entry that causes the Problems with unique constraints
@Data
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"projectId", "userId", "date"}))
public class ProjectEntry extends CoreEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long projectId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Duration duration;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate anyDate;

    //getter setter

}
```

Service Impl method

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public Association create(Association association ) {
    checkNotNull(association);
    association.setId(null);

    association.getProjects().forEach(projectEntry -> {
        checkObjectNotNull(projectEntry );
        projectEntryRepo.save(projectEntry);
    });
   // Here is the problem
}
return associationRepo.save(association);
```

Here an exception will be thrown, when the constraint is violated. 
But if the first object of the List is valid and the second violates the Unique constraint, the first Entry-create will be still commited. But none should be commited, if one is wrong. All Requests should rollback. 
How should I annotated the method or deal with this issue ?

Comment: it would be nice if you put the Association Entity's schema

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception_NAME.class,...})
    public Association create(Association association ) {...}
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work, the way it seems to. The first successfull request will still be commited.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Valid` to validate `Set<ProjectEntry>`

Try to update your code as below

`@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])` it will save the `ProjectEntity`

> Association class

```
// Associated entry
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"userId", "associationDate"}))
public class Association extends coreEntity {

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private Long userId;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private LocalDate associationDate;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private LocalTime start;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       private LocalTime end;

       private Duration breakTime;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       @Valid
       @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
       private Set<ProjectEntry> projects;
    // getter setter

}
```

> Service Impl

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Association create(Association association ) {
    checkNotNull(association);
    association.setId(null);
    return associationRepo.save(association);
}
```

Comment: This has the exactly same behavior like everything I tried. Exception occurs, but the first correct Entry of the list will be persisted and nothing else. But I want to rollback all commits of this transaction.

Comment: I have updated the answer try to add @Valid annotation.

Comment: Seems to have no effect. 
@Valid seems to only work with "@NotNull , @NotBlank" etc not constraint values. Also it is only for "Controller annotation"

Answer (score 0):

Set autocommit to false at start of function and after processing all objects successfully then commit the changes

Comment: How can I do this for the single function ?